# How do I get variables used in model/function pass to TensorFlowEstimator

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

How do I get variables (e.g., embedding table, RNN variables, etc.) after the model fitting, when using TensorFlowEstimator for fitting, such as in this [skflow example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/language_model.py)? As tf.all_variables() returns empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_variable_names()` in estimator.

Basically, you need to get graph and then call `all_variables()`. For example:

`with self._graph.as_default():
    print([v.name for v in variables.all_variables()])`